# Choosing different UITableViewCells depending on available text or image content

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

**I want to display different `UITableViewCell`s depending on what content is available . How can I accomplish that ?**

*Example:*

Lets say I have a custom `UITableViewCell` whose `contentView` has a `UILabel`, `UITextField` and a `UIImageView` as subviews. The `UILabel` is located on the top of the cell, above the `UIImageView` which is next to the `UITextField`. Depending on which contents for these views is available, I would like to only display the available parts and enlarge the other views. e.G: If there is missing the UILabel context I don't want to have a blank space at the top of the cell. If I don't have an image, the text field should start at the very left side of the cell.

There should be many newspaper/tv applications out there which had to solved exact the same problem...

*Approaches:*

*(i)* Using the same custom cell where I somehow rearrange the subviews

*(ii)* Calling different custom `UITableViewCell`'s depending on what content is available

For both approaches I am having issues finding a path to solve this problem. My `UITableView` content size is dynamic and can have a few rows or many.

**Is there any other approach I am missing out or if not which approach is best practice?**

Comment: I decided to go for approach *(i)* due to the answer given by Anomie. It works great! I decided to go for this approach because otherwise I would have had to create 5 different cells. Now I only have one cell which changes his layout depending on which content is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either approach works, although I would probably prefer *(i)*.

For *(i)*, reuse is easy. Just make sure you clear out the old data when reusing, have your UITableViewCell's `layoutSubviews` method lay the subviews out appropriately to match whatever data is available, and be sure to call `setNeedsLayout` when you change the data. The advantage here is that the rest of your code doesn't need to care about which data is available or not, and your table may not even have to care if the cell suddenly gets an image added (unless it needs to know that the cell height changed or something). The disadvantage is that the cell's implementation is more complex, and the layout cannot be completely defined in IB.

For *(ii)*, each different custom UITableViewCell type must have its own `reuseIdentifier`, and then use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` with the identifier appropriate to the available data. The advantage here is that the individual cell types are simpler (and can probably be done entirely in IB), while the disadvantage is that you have to have several of them for each possible combination of available data. Also, you would need to have the UITableView reload the cell (e.g. using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) if the type needs to change.

Comment: Thx for the great answer! The cell height will variate depending on the `UILabel`and `UITextField` content height needed to display the entire text. Would you still go for *(i)* in that case?

Comment: @braintt: The issue of the cell height is unrelated to which method you use to create the UITableViewCell objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your *(ii)* idea is the way to go to my mind. As you say, you design two customs `UITableViewCell` (.m, .h and .xib) you don't forget to define there `CellIdentifier` in interface Builder and when your delegate `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called you choose to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` the appropriate UITableViewCell template.